# Preventing multiple users on one account

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

I would like to ask you:
Imagine that you have a site and there is some extra content for registered members who paid a monthly fee. How to ensure that some group of friends are not using just one registered user account with access to everything? I was thinking that maybe storing IPs but what about users with a dynamic IPs? Maybe SMS authentication would be the right way but that costs money and it is annoying for users. I dont know. Any ideas? I am using PHP with Zend Framework.

Thank you,
T.

Comment: Before you spend your time on it, consider the worth of such an implementation. Irrespective of the lock downs you are going to put down, people are going to hack their way a work around it. So consider factors like, does it cost money if they did it (eg., bandwidth costs) or you are just losing new customers sign ups. One cheap and some what effective option is to disable concurrent access. This will annoy the people who use the same login and maybe encourage them to sign up for new accounts. Sorry, probably not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I expected this question to have at least 1k upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce each account not to have more than one open session at any given time.

A session should be identified by a cookie stored and retrieved in https only, and it should time out, if not kept alive by some activity, after a reasonable time (e.g., 15 minutes), in order for a user who removes or loses the cookie without explicitly logging out to be able to log in again (and for security reasons too). You cannot rely on the cookie to time out, but this is probably clear to you already.

Of course, this will not prevent a "time-share" usage of an account by several users, but such a usage is often not a real problem. If you require bothersome login procedures many good customers will probably run away. You should rather tolerate a small percentage of abuse.

I also agree with all that has been written by Darwindeeds in a comment to your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I agree with you and also with darwindeeds. I am gonna think a bit about that and probably just implement what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like how steam login works.
If you try to access from any other computer it will send a verification code to your registered email and once you enter that you are allowed to login, am sure no on share s their email accounts.